# перезадание переменной типа "класс"

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Не совсем понимаю, как работать с классами в си

Допустим, у меня есть такой простой класс:

```
class matrix{
    public:
    int *X;
    matrix(int N){
        X= new int [N];
    }
    ~matrix(){
        delete [] X;
    }
}
```

И вот я задаю новый экземпляр этого класса:

```
matrix a(5);
```

Как мне теперь перезадать его? Я делаю так:

```
a.~matrix();
a = matrix(7);
```

Правильно?
И теперь самое интересное - в этом классе есть ещё функция

```
SET(int I, int x){
    X[I]=x;
}

int main(){
    matrix a(7);

    a.SET(0,3); //тут работает

    a.~matrix();
    a = matrix(9);

    a.SET(0,3);//если есть эта строка то не просто вылетает программа,
               //так ещё и без сообщения об ошибке
    a.SET(1,3);// а вот эта работает хорошо

return 0;
}
```

Что я не учёл или сделал не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы называете *перезаданием*, на самом деле простое *присваивание*. Вам в вашем классе нужно определить оператор присваивания и конструктор копирования. Вообще, это справедливо для любого сколь-нибудь нетривиального класса...

Я бы делал так:

```
class matrix {
public:
    matrix(int N)
    {
        x = new int[N];
        n = N;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            x[i] = 0;
    }

    matrix(const matrix& m)
    {
        x = new int[m.n];
        n = m.n;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            x[i] = m.x[i];
    }

    matrix& operator=(const matrix& m)
    {
        if (this == &m) return *this;
        delete[] x;
        x = new int[m.n];
        n = m.n;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            x[i] = m.x[i];
        return *this;
    }

    ~matrix()
    {
        delete[]x;
    }
private:
    int *x;
    size_t n;
}
```

Вернее, я бы делал не так, но для простоты давайте именно так.

У вас все неприятности из-за отсутствия операторов присваивания и копирующего конструктора.

Теперь вот это

```
a.~matrix();
a = matrix(7);
```

вам не нужно, просто

```
a = matrix(7);
```

достаточно (оператор сам освободит память).

```
a.~matrix();
a = matrix(9);

a.SET(0,3);//если есть эта строка то не просто вылетает программа,
           //так ещё и без сообщения об ошибке
```

Тут у вас не работало, ибо получалось следующее: удаление массива. Создание временной матрицы с 9 элементами. Из-за отсутствия копирующего конструктора и оператора присваивания - простое присваивание адреса (а не создание нового массива). Уничтожение временной матрицы с освобождением памяти (указатель на которую остается в матрице `a`). Попытка записи в уже освобожденную память...

Все просто. Главное - пишите **все** конструкторы, присваивание и деструктор.

Можно еще и перемещающие писать, но это уже потом, сначала разберитесь с этим...

Еще два замечания.
В `SET` проверяйте выход индекса за границы массива.
НЕ ЗЛОУПОТРЕБЛЯЙТЕ БОЛЬШИМИ БУКВАМИ В ИМЕНАХ :)

Comment: Доработал конструкторы - действительно заработало, большое спасибо. Ещё пара вопрос для лучшего понимания:

Comment: Какие именно вопросы?

Comment: 1) верно ли я понял, что по сути эти два конструктора реализуют по отдельности оператор присваивания "=" (ну, это даже вроде как из названия видно) и правую часть самого равенства? 2) что в операторе присваивания делает строчка "if(this == &M) return *this;" и зачем она нужна? 3) если у меня до этого не создавался нормально новый массив, то почему другие элементы, не нулевой, менялись нормально? Я их печатал, работало.

Comment: 1) Конструктор копирования очень *похож* на оператор присваивания, так как делает по сути то же самое. Но это не всегда так. 2) Эта строчка проверяет, не присваиваете ли вы объект самому себе (типа `x = x;`). 3) При ошибках вам никто не *гарантирует* того или иного поведения. Так стандарт и пишет - **undefined behaviour**. Грубо говоря, программа в этот момент может гимн начать играть :) Худшее, что может произойти - когда все **выглядит работоспособным**. Лучшее - аварийный вылет программы.